# Cron jobs in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I was wondering if it was possible to delete or modify data in mongodb collection at any particular time provided.

Think of it as trivial data that has to be deleted/updated at the end of the day.
Point me in a direction.

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron

Comment: @Michel I request you to right away right a book on Meteor. We seriously look forward to it, you are an ocean of knowledge.

Comment: Much obliged @AnkurSoni!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two good options to do cron jobs in Meteor:

- https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron
- https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection

From my experience, if your use case is simple and you need a fast, lightweight solution [meteor-synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) should be ok. In case your task is more complicated you need more control on the jobs then go with [jobs-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection)

Comment: thanks for the help meteor-synced-cron did it for me.

Comment: 2020 update: both packages are no longer maintained

Answer (score 2):

The standard npm [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) works fine. E.g.

```js
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  new CronJob({
    cronTime: '00 30 02 * * *',
    // use this wrapper if you want to work with mongo:
    onTick: Meteor.bindEnvironment(() => {
      // stuff happens
    })
    start: true,
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With meteor I didn't get standard node packages like `cron` working properly as meteor complaints and shows a message to use Fibers. For a simple daily task I've created a function which will directly use Meteor.setTimeout(). This way it will keep the Meteor environment available so you can do you daily db cleanup.

It uses the node package later just for the schedule when to fire the 'cron' job. You can replace yourDailyCleanup with the name of your function to be called.

```
    import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
    import later from 'later';

    function scheduleTimeout(sched, fn) {
      const nowMilli = Date.now();
      const next = later.schedule(sched).next(1,nowMilli+1001);
      console.log('next schedule',next);
      const diffMile = next.getTime() - nowMilli;

      Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
        scheduleTimeout(sched,fn);
        fn();
      } , diffMile );
    }   

    Meteor.startup(function() {
      console.log('Startup');
      later.date.localTime();
//      scheduleTimeout( later.parse.recur().every(2).minute(), function() { console.log('test job');} );
      scheduleTimeout( later.parse.recur().on('23:00:00').time(), yourDailyCleanup );
    });
```

The code is based on the package [percolatestudio:meteor-synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron/blob/master/synced-cron-server.js) which you can also use when you need more functionality.